# What is Difference window and View in Esper?

Tags: esper, epl

I'm learning Esper, CEP Processing engine, but I can't understand about view and window.

There are so looks like, but I feel something difference. But I cant understand it. someone say to me about that simply?

thx for read, and sry for my not good english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A data window is a view that always retains a set of events.
A derived-value view is a view that does not retain events and instead outputs some derived information.
Both are views i.e. can be used in the from-clause together with other views.